# font expansion : auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts

Tags: templates, acm, acmart, sigconf

I downloaded the LaTeX template "sample-sigconf" from Overleaf.

While it compiles without errors using Overleaf's compiler, I encounter the following error message when compiling it with TeXstudio :

> pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with
> scalable fonts.

Please refer to the screenshot for further details.

**Note:** I downloaded the LaTeX template from the following Overleaf link:
[ACM - SIG Proceedings Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-sig-proceedings-template/bmvfhcdnxfty)

Here is a sample .tex file:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}

\acmConference[Conference acronym 'XX]{Make sure to enter the correct
  conference title from your rights confirmation emai}{June 03--05,
  2018}{Woodstock, NY}
  
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}


\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}


\author{Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}
  \streetaddress{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}
  \city{Hekla}
  \country{Iceland}}
\email{larst@affiliation.org}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}

\begin{abstract}
  A clear and well-documented \LaTeX\ document is presented as an
  article formatted for publication by ACM in a conference proceedings
  or journal publication. Based on the ``acmart'' document class, this
  article presents and explains many of the common variations, as well
  as many of the formatting elements an author may use in the
  preparation of the documentation of their work.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Do, Not, Us, This, Code, Put, the, Correct, Terms, for,
  Your, Paper}

\begin{teaserfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sampleteaser}
  \caption{Seattle Mariners at Spring Training, 2010.}
  \Description{Enjoying the baseball game from the third-base
  seats. Ichiro Suzuki preparing to bat.}
  \label{fig:teaser}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
text


\end{document}
%%
%% End of file `sample-sigconf.tex'.
```

And, here is the new screenshot of the error log after compilation:

[image]

[image]

**I also run it using `cmd`. I received the same error message: `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.`**

Here's the log file:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3930]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


F:\Folder>pdflatex sample-sigconf.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 24.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(sample-sigconf.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>
(acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2024/01/21 v2.02 Typesetting articles for the Associatio
n for Computing Machinery
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype-pdftex.def)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.cfg))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/totpages\totpages.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/everyshi\everyshi.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/environ\environ.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/trimspaces\trimspaces.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\textcase.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperxmp\hyperxmp.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifmtarg\ifmtarg.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/oberdiek\ifdraft.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ncctools\manyfoot.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ncctools\nccfoots.sty))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftex\glyphtounicode.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/cmap\cmap.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty<<t1.cmap>>)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine\libertine.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fontaxes\fontaxes.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine\LinLibertine_I.tex))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/inconsolata\zi4.sty
`inconsolata-zi4' v1.12, 2019/05/17 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\newtxmath.sty
`newtxmath' v1.732, 2023/11/05 Math macros based originally on txfonts (msharpe
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/oberdiek\centernot.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/binhex\binhex.tex)
amsthm NOT loaded
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption-ams-smf.sto)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/comment\comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'CCSXML'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty)
Special comment 'acks'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine\t1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preprint\balance.sty)
Excluding comment 'screenonly' Include comment 'printonly'
Include comment 'anonsuppress'
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def)
(sample-sigconf.aux) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\omlnxlmi.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxexa.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\lmsntxsy.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\lmxntxexx.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine\ot1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd)<<ot1.cm
ap>><<oml.cmap>> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxmia.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxsym.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newtx\untxsyc.fd) (sample-sigconf.out)
(sample-sigconf.out)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/upquote\upquote.sty)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine\t1linuxbiolinumt-tlf.fd)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\mt-msa.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\mt-msb.cfg)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/libertine\ts1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `TotPages' on page 1 undefined on input line 54.

[1.1{C:/Users/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...
l.60 \end{document}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on sample-sigconf.log.
```

**Note 2:** **I have this problem only with all ACM LaTex templates.**

**Note 3: The `libertine` package has been installed. See the screenshot below:**
[image]

Comment: This is a routine error. Many fonts are available in several file formats. Overleaf correctly selected a font in scalable format (as opposed to bitmap). But your local installation is trying to use a bitmap font, because the scalable font could not be found. More likely than not, you need to install another font package. Wild guess: package `cm-super`.

Comment: @rallg , I haven't made any changes to the template. How can I resolve this error? Could it be related to TexStudio?

Comment: @Questioner No, it is definitely not caused by TeXStudio. As rallg said, the explanation is probably that OverLeaf has scalable versions of fonts installed which you only have bitmap versions of. That means the same document may give an error locally but not on OverLeaf. Since you've provided no code, we can only guess what you're doing. Installing `cm-super` is a reasonable guess, but if you want to be sure or that doesn't work, provide a minimal example which produces the error and the log. But never provide images of code or errors. Always copy-paste into your post as text.

Comment: @cfr , I downloaded the LaTeX template from the following Overleaf link: [ACM - SIG Proceedings Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-sig-proceedings-template/bmvfhcdnxfty)

Comment: @Questioner That's not really relevant. The same thing is going to compile OK for me if it compiles on OverLeaf. (At least, it won't fail with the error you're getting.) You need to do as suggested above.

Comment: @cfr , I installed `cm-super` using MiKTeX Console, but nothing changed.

Comment: What is your platform? I suppose Windows (Linux/Mac people tend to phrase questions another way). Do you have the TeXworks program on your computer? Try building with TeXworks, and see what the console output says. Let us know. Even better if you can directly compile by command line. We need to know exactly what happened in the log file. Incidentally, can you compile anything at all (small test document) on your device?

Comment: @rallg ,I use TeXstudio on Windows and have added complementary information to the question. Should I also include the entire log file? It's a bit lengthy.

Comment: @rallg , I also run it using `cmd`. I received the same error message: `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.`

Comment: @Questioner Create a *minimal* document to reproduce the error and then post the log from that, which should not be huge.

Comment: @cfr , I updated the question. Also, apparently, I have this problem only with all ACM LaTex templates.

Comment: @Questioner Take stuff out of the example until you find the bit causing the error. Do you have Linux Libertine and Biolinum installed? E.g. `LinLibertineTI.pfb` and `LinBiolinumT.pfb` should be somewhere TeX can find them. Also, you need Latin Modern, but I'm assuming that's unlikely to be missing?

Comment: as others have said, this is either due to a font being available as bitmap only, or even missing entirely. To find out which fonts are problematic, add this line: `\PassOptionsToPackage{expansion=false}{microtype}` at the very beginning, even before `\documentclass`, then run pdflatex and open the log file. At the very end of it, you'll find a list of all fonts used. If there's one (or more) with the ending `.pk`, this tells you which fonts have to be fixed.

Comment: @Robert , The new log file is found here: https://ctxt.io/2/AADwSEFKEQ

Comment: ok, so there seems to be a problem with the libertine package. Either you didn't recreate the map files, or the package hasn't been fully installed, would be my guess. You can fix both in the Miktex package manager or whatever it's called nowadays (I'm not using Miktex myself, so I don't know how).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of @Robert, I uninstalled and reinstalled `libertine` package via MikTeX Console and the problem was resolved.